# Convert decimal stored as varchar to datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, varchar

I've inherited a MySQL database with a date column type of `Varchar`.

The column contains decimal strings. For example: `41143.646585648`.

How would I go about converting this into DateTime format?

Comment: Thankyou for linking this, however the linked question presumes that my date is stored in the format of mm/dd/yyyy or similar. My issue that is I have a decimal number

Comment: a datetime stored as decimal in a varchar column: Time to hunt down the developer!

Comment: What does the number mean? You say it is a representation of a date and time, but in what way? It is hard to guess for you.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like Microsoft Excel date format.  Is it?  (Should have mentioned in the question if so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to know is the date the original developer defined as the value zero.  Then it's a simple matter of adding the integer number of days to that date, then multiplying the fractional part by 86400 to get seconds and doing the arithmetic to determine the hour, minute and second.

If you have a row where you know the actual date and the stored value you can determine the zero date easily by subtraction.

Comment: Marking this as the answer. It was a very poor and vague question and you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

You could string replace the dot, but the remaining count of numbers is to high for a unix timestamp. I don't know how the date was converted to decimal. Maybe you should split your string rather than string replace.

Maybe this code gives you some ideas for a solution:

```
#SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(REPLACE('41143.646585648', '.', '')); # Does not work due to wrong amount of numbers in string

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(REPLACE('13577.77916', '.', '')); # works
```