# Convert DECIMAL(16,4) into DATETIME MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need to convert a timestamp that gets stored as DECIMAL(16, 4) in the database to DATETIME when pulling it out from the database in a select, if possible.

The way it gets stored in the database is as follows:

```
$time = function_exists('microtime') ? microtime(true) : time();
$submit_time = number_format($time, 4, '.', '');
```

Than, `$submit_time` goes into database with column `submit_time`.

Is it possible to extract this value and `CONVERT` it to a `DATETIME` value when pulling it from the database?  The reason I would like to convert it to `DATETIME` is because it would be easier to manage when searching dates that are being outputted using pagination.

Been looking at the MySQL `CONVERT` Function, and have tried the following, but it outputs empty content:

`SELECT CONVERT(submit_time, DATETIME) AS datetime`

Any help is greatly appreciated ofcourse!

Please note, I've seen the Answer that is tagged to this question, and it does not help my situation.  Firstly, all answers, save 1, are returning PHP code that converts it, and Secondly the supposed answer in SQL for CONVERT does not work in MySQL for a number of reasons, 1 being that in SQL, looks like there are 3 parameters for CONVERT, but in MySQL, only 2.  Also, CONVERT in MySQL either works differently, or is not the correct function and that answer is wrong.

Comment: This should be of help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248678/convert-decimal-stored-as-varchar-to-datetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert decimal(16,4) to DATE or DATETIME in SQL or PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102749/how-to-convert-decimal16-4-to-date-or-datetime-in-sql-or-php)

Comment: No it is not, as for reasons outlined in the question.  Thanks just the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on needed accuracy

`select from_unixtime(round(submit_time)) as datetime -- 2012-04-10 09:00:26`

or

`select from_unixtime(submit_time) as datetime -- 2012-04-10 09:00:25.5900`

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd 1 did it right for me, just needed to use `DATE_FORMAT` on it and extract only the year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds from it that way.  Cheers.  `ROUND` caused some issues, as it seems to have been rounding the entire string up instead.